# How to troubleshoot a wireless networking regression?

Tags: wireless, ralink, debugging

I've been experiencing this [perhaps slightly odd bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+source/network-manager/+bug/619093).

It works flawlessly in Lucid, but not in Maverick and Natty. I find it seems to work when I'm booting a partition everyday (as I do for my main 10.10 partition) but for my 11.04 testing partition it's a real pain - usually refusing to connect.

I think the problem might be due to the PSK authentication/encryption my router is using, but I don't really know anything about this.

So given that I have both a working (10.04) and not-working (10.10 and 11.04) installs, how can I troubleshoot my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine where the regression is: Test Maverick with the Lucid kernel and vice versa, and also test kernels from the [mainline PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/). If you can make it work in Maverick with an older kernel and break in Lucid with a newer kernel, it's a kernel regression. If not, it's a problem in the userland.

If it is a kernel regression, determine the newest working kernel and then perform a [git bisection](http://www.reactivated.net/weblog/archives/2006/01/using-git-bisect-to-find-buggy-kernel-patches/) to find the exact commit where it stopped working.

If it is a userland bug you will have to dig into the packages involved with wireless.